# parent.window.location redirection from spring mvc modelandview

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

My application consists of few iframes. In Spring MVC is there a way to redirect to the parent page instead of the current iframe? For example in javascript we can do parent.window.location to load the page in parent instead of using window.location which would load only in the iframe.

The following view loads login.go in current iframe, but i want the login.go to be displayed in whole page (parent)

```
return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/login.go", false, true, true));
```

Any ideas please..

Answer (score 3):

This is certainly another reason why [frames are evil.](http://apptools.com/rants/framesevil.php)

It's not possible to break out of a frame without using javascript.

Comment: This is sad to hear. As my entire project is dependent on this.